# I can't run scan task for trivy 0.24.2 in harbor

Tags: harbor, trivy

harbor 2.4 migrate from 2.3

get logs

```
Jul 14 14:19:55 172.26.0.1 trivy-adapter[13699]: {"error":"running trivy: exit status 1: Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -format\n\nNAME:\n   trivy - A simple and comprehensive vulnerability scanner for containers\n\nUSAGE:\n   trivy [global options] command [command options] target\n\nVERSION:\n   0.24.2\n\nCOMMANDS:\n   image, i          scan an image\n   filesystem, fs    scan local filesystem for language-specific dependencies and config files\n   rootfs            scan rootfs\n   repository, repo  scan remote repository\n   client, c         client mode\n   server, s         server mode\n   config, conf      scan config files\n   plugin, p         manage plugins\n   help, h           Shows a list of commands or help for one command\n\nGLOBAL OPTIONS:\n   --quiet, -q        suppress progress bar and log output (default: false) [$TRIVY_QUIET]\n   --debug, -d        debug mode (default: false) [$TRIVY_DEBUG]\n   --cache-dir value  cache directory (default: \"/home/scanner/.cache/trivy\") [$TRIVY_CACHE_DIR]\n   --help, -h         show help (default: false)\n   --version, -v      print the version (default: false)\n2022-07-14T06:19:55.922Z\t\u001b[31mFATAL\u001b[0m\tflag provided but not defined: -format\n","level":"error","msg":"Error while retrieving vulnerability DB version","time":"2022-07-14T06:19:55Z"}
Jul 14 14:20:03 172.26.0.1 trivy-adapter[13699]: {"exit_code":1,"image_ref":"core:8080/devops-ci/project-center@sha256:3da9c93c988e25708371fdb4fb9df852671980f22e8bcbb57ec543771f2aad05","level":"error","msg":"Running trivy failed","std_out":"2022-07-14T06:20:03.390Z\t\u001b[31mFATAL\u001b[0m\tscan error: image scan failed: failed analysis: analyze error: timeout: context deadline exceeded\n","time":"2022-07-14T06:20:03Z"}
Jul 14 14:20:03 172.26.0.1 trivy-adapter[13699]: {"error":"running trivy wrapper: running trivy: exit status 1: 2022-07-14T06:20:03.390Z\t\u001b[31mFATAL\u001b[0m\tscan error: image scan failed: failed analysis: analyze error: timeout: context deadline exceeded\n","level":"error","msg":"Scan failed","time":"2022-07-14T06:20:03Z"}
Jul 14 14:20:07 172.26.0.1 trivy-adapter[13699]: {"error":"running trivy wrapper: running trivy: exit status 1: 2022-07-14T06:20:03.390Z\t\u001b[31mFATAL\u001b[0m\tscan error: image scan failed: failed analysis: analyze error: timeout: context deadline exceeded\n","level":"error","msg":"Scan job failed","scan_job_id":"17090e29c76fb979d3788b95","time":"2022-07-14T06:20:07Z"}
Jul 14 14:20:55 172.26.0.1 trivy-adapter[13699]: {"exit_code":1,"level":"error","msg":"Running trivy failed","std_out":"Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -format\n\nNAME:\n   trivy - A simple and comprehensive vulnerability scanner for containers\n\nUSAGE:\n   trivy [global options] command [command options] target\n\nVERSION:\n   0.24.2\n\nCOMMANDS:\n   image, i          scan an image\n   filesystem, fs    scan local filesystem for language-specific dependencies and config files\n   rootfs            scan rootfs\n   repository, repo  scan remote repository\n   client, c         client mode\n   server, s         server mode\n   config, conf      scan config files\n   plugin, p         manage plugins\n   help, h           Shows a list of commands or help for one command\n\nGLOBAL OPTIONS:\n   --quiet, -q        suppress progress bar and log output (default: false) [$TRIVY_QUIET]\n   --debug, -d        debug mode (default: false) [$TRIVY_DEBUG]\n   --cache-dir value  cache directory (default: \"/home/scanner/.cache/trivy\") [$TRIVY_CACHE_DIR]\n   --help, -h         show help (default: false)\n   --version, -v      print the version (default: false)\n2022-07-14T06:20:55.927Z\t\u001b[31mFATAL\u001b[0m\tflag provided but not defined: -format\n","time":"2022-07-14T06:20:55Z"}
Jul 14 14:20:55 172.26.0.1 trivy-adapter[13699]: {"error":"running trivy: exit status 1: Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -format\n\nNAME:\n   trivy - A simple and comprehensive vulnerability scanner for containers\n\nUSAGE:\n   trivy [global options] command [command options] target\n\nVERSION:\n   0.24.2\n\nCOMMANDS:\n   image, i          scan an image\n   filesystem, fs    scan local filesystem for language-specific dependencies and config files\n   rootfs            scan rootfs\n   repository, repo  scan remote repository\n   client, c         client mode\n   server, s         server mode\n   config, conf      scan config files\n   plugin, p         manage plugins\n   help, h           Shows a list of commands or help for one command\n\nGLOBAL OPTIONS:\n   --quiet, -q        suppress progress bar and log output (default: false) [$TRIVY_QUIET]\n   --debug, -d        debug mode (default: false) [$TRIVY_DEBUG]\n   --cache-dir value  cache directory (default: \"/home/scanner/.cache/trivy\") [$TRIVY_CACHE_DIR]\n   --help, -h         show help (default: false)\n   --version, -v      print the version (default: false)\n2022-07-14T06:20:55.927Z\t\u001b[31mFATAL\u001b[0m\tflag provided but not defined: -format\n","level":"error","msg":"Error while retrieving vulnerability DB version","time":"2022-07-14T06:20:55Z"}
```

**Environment:**

- Harbor version: 2.4
- Harbor Scanner Adapter for Trivy version: 0.24.2
- Harbor installation process ([Installer script][harbor-installer], [Helm chart][harbor-helm], etc.):
  I use ./install.sh --with-chartmuseum --with-trivy to install

If I want to uninstall trivy and the data about trivy how to do that?

---

after reinstall trivy

I can scan but some image scan get error

[image]

```
2022-07-14T07:20:00Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:385]: {
  "uuid": "43a2c8b7-0345-11ed-885e-0242c0a80009",
  "name": "Trivy",
  "description": "The Trivy scanner adapter",
  "url": "http://trivy-adapter:8080",
  "disabled": false,
  "is_default": true,
  "health": "healthy",
  "auth": "",
  "access_credential": "[HIDDEN]",
  "skip_certVerify": false,
  "use_internal_addr": true,
  "adapter": "Trivy",
  "vendor": "Aqua Security",
  "version": "v0.24.2",
  "create_time": "2022-07-14T07:19:14.07259Z",
  "update_time": "2022-07-14T07:19:14.072592Z"
}
2022-07-14T07:20:00Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:385]: {
  "registry": {
    "url": "http://core:8080",
    "authorization": "[HIDDEN]"
  },
  "artifact": {
    "namespace_id": 86,
    "repository": "adoptopenjdk/openjdk11",
    "tag": "jdk-11.0.3_7-alpine",
    "digest": "sha256:b150d823c46bc490799bc15ba1d6b6d5b15295791b1f727ded73a77d78eee280",
    "mime_type": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
  }
}
2022-07-14T07:20:00Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:167]: Report mime types: [application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1]
2022-07-14T07:20:00Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:222]: Get report for mime type: application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1
2022-07-14T07:20:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:52Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:20:57Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:52Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:21:57Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:52Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:22:57Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:52Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:23:57Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:52Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:24:57Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:52Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:25:57Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:02Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:07Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:12Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:17Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:22Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:27Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:32Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:37Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:42Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:47Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:53Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:26:58Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:03Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:08Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:13Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:18Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:23Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:28Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:33Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:38Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:43Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:48Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:53Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:27:58Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:03Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:08Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:13Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:18Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:23Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:28Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:33Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:38Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:43Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:48Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:53Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:28:58Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:29:03Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:29:08Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:29:13Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:29:18Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:29:23Z [INFO] [/pkg/scan/job.go:243]: Report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1 is not ready yet, retry after 5 seconds
2022-07-14T07:29:28Z [ERROR] [/pkg/scan/job.go:292]: check scan report with mime type application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1: running trivy wrapper: running trivy: exit status 1: 2022-07-14T07:29:25.302Z [31mFATAL[0m  scan error: image scan failed: failed analysis: analyze error: timeout: context deadline exceeded
: general response handler: unexpected status code: 500, expected: 200
```